# Xcode 3.2.1 and C++ string fails!

Tags: c++, xcode

In Xcode 3.2.1 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard, I open a project under:
Command Line Tool of type C++ stdc++.
I have the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string myvar;
        cout << "Enter something: " << endl;
    cin >> myvar;
    cout << endl << myvar << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine, and prompts me to "Enter Something". When I type in something, and then press enter, I get the following error:

```
myproject(766) malloc: *** error for object 0x1000041c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

When compiling on an earlier version of Xcode (3.1.2) on a different computer (opened the project with the 'command line utility' option, which does not exist in 3.2.1), the code runs with NO PROBLEM.

Does anybody know what's going on?
Thanks,
Yuval

Comment: The second XCode matches mine it just works - what version of XCode have you got on the one with the problem

Comment: the one with the problem is version 3.2.1

Comment: From Xcode 3.2.1. connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/… says must be installed on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and higher. So do you really mean Leopard?

Comment: I am on Leopard, not Snow Leopard... Can Xcode 3.2.1 only run on Snow Leopard?

Comment: oh never mind! i'm running SNOW LEOPARD on that machine. what's the recommended course of action to resolve the problem?

Comment: Confirmed that I see this on XCode 3.2.1 on my Snow Leopard mbp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I'm not experiencing this issue in Release mode for `x86_64`. But I am seeing the issue in Debug `x86_64`. If I follow the [directions given by Howard in this post](http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2009-09/msg00526.html), I'm able to get it running in debug mode:

1. Project -> Edit Active Target ...
2. Click Build tab
3. Search for "preprocessor"
4. Delete `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1`

Build and run, you'll notice it works. Another interesting observation is that using `__gnu_debug::string` (from the `<debug/string>` header) alone does not trigger the error.

**EDIT: from the horses mouth ([known issues in XCode 3.2.1](http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-DontLinkElementID_1))**

> The default gcc 4.2 compiler is not compatible with the Standard C++ Library Debug Mode. C++ programs compiled with Xcode 3.2 may not work in the Debug configuration. To fix this, set the Compiler Version to 4.0, or edit the Debug configuration’s Preprocessor Macros and remove the entries:
>   `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1`

You can do this for all projects by navigating to `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application/Command Line Tool/C++ Tool/C++Tool.xcodeproj/` and editing `project.pbxproj` and deleting the lines around line 138:

```
"_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1",
"_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1",
```

Comment: Meta-comment: you aren't really doing much to help your debugging though.

Comment: does this disable debugging for the project completely?

Comment: is there any way make that affect all projects in xcode rather than doing it for every single one?

Comment: You can also change from GCC 4.2 to GCC 4.0.

Comment: I realize this is well after the fact, but Xcode 3.2.2 "fixes" the problem by disabling C++ Standard Template Library Debug Mode. Per an updated version of the Xcode link provided above: "C++ Standard Template Library Debug Mode (GLIBCXX_DEBUG) is not supported with gcc 4.2. In Xcode 3.2 and 3.2.1 this would cause C++ programs compiled with gcc 4.2 to behave oddly, usually with string I/O to streams. In Xcode 3.2.2 the macros that invoke STL Debug Mode are suppressed when using gcc 4.2 so that C++ programs behave correctly when built with the Debug configuration."

Answer (score 2):

An easier way of accomplishing the same thing: paste these lines at the very beginning of your program (before any #include statements):

```
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 1
#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC
```

Obviously, this will only affect the current project.