# g++ and file read, weird behaviour with Xcode/Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, xcode

I am writing a program that reads a file, whose first two lines are:

```
Field of space: 0.4
226981 20
```

Then I want to pass 226981 and 20 to integer variables. So I do:

```
 ifstream vfile(file_name, ios::in);      
 vfile.getline(header,FILENAME);  // Read the header-line      
 vfile >> nTot >> file_size;
```

If I compile the program with g++; I get for `nTot` and `file_size` the right values, `226981` and `20`, but If do it for Mac OS X Snow Leopard with the last `Xcode`, I get `0` and `1634000000` respectively.

Has anyone experienced this kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` issue - make sure you have the latest Xcode installed, that `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` is set the same for all your code and libraries, and you might also want to check the [xcode-users](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/xcode-users) mailing list.

Comment: yes, it makes more sense as I only get this error with Xcode and Snow Leopard (not Leopard before)

Comment: I found here the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603300/xcode-3-2-1-and-c-string-fails

Answer (score 1):

The call `vfile.getline(header, FILENAME)` is probably incorrect. The signature is:

```
istream::getline(char *s, streamsize n)
```

where `s` points to the output buffer and `n` is the size of the buffer.

I doubt that your `FILENAME` is an integer... it's probably a `char const*` that g++ implicitly casts to a `streamsize`? (Eeuw... use `-Wall -ansi` if you can.) This would have a compiler-dependent value, and if it is smaller than the length of the line, this would throw your stream into an error state (set the `failbit`). Subsequent reads will then fail until the error state is reset.

You should use

```
getline(vfile, header);
```

instead, where `header` is a `std::string`.