# cin not working with empty string when_GLIBCXX_DEBUG on Windows?

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, mingw

Very Strange behavior happened to me. I am using latest Cygwin32, Cygwin64 and MinGW32 with GCC 4.9.2 , 4.9.2 and 4.8.1 respectively on Windows 7 64-bit. I am testing also on 32-bit Linux using GCC 4.8.2.

So on all systems this works

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string s,t;
int main(){
  cin>>s>>t;
  cout<<s;
}
```

and this works

```
#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string s="a",t="b";
int main(){
    cin>>s>>t;
    cout<<s;
}
```

but the next one crashes on Windows after inputting the first string on the 3 configurations mentioned above, but works correctly on Linux:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string s,t;
int main(){
    cin>>s>>t;
    cout<<s;
}
```

Clearly the only difference is that the string is empty before inputting, and `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` is enabled.

First, is this a reproducible problem? i.e. does it happen on every PC with the same configuration , or only my PC? Second, What is the problem? What should I do? I clearly need  `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to debug other STL structures in the code.

Comment: I observed the same behavior.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you include `<iostream>` and `<string>` separately rather than `<bits/stdc++.h>`?

Comment: I am very suspecious of the non standard header `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Would prefer a test that used `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` and did not use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @user657267 The same happens if I remove #include <bits/stdc++.h> and use <iostream> and <string> separately

Comment: @LokiAstari The same happens if I remove using namespace std; and use std::string and std::string

Comment: Could you try the [nuwen MinGW](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) and post the results? It works for me.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I have just tried nuwen MinGW , and it works beautifully without crash as Linux , on the contrary of official MinGW32, Cygwin32 and Cygwin64.

Comment: "What should I do?" Please file a bug report, as usual when you find a bug.

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb I had a vastly better experience with the nuwen distro so far, and you appear to have hit a bug in those other distros you mentioned. You should file a bug report for that. But good to see you got it working.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Where should I file a bug report? and to which project?

Comment: Reporting it to both cygwin (https://cygwin.com/problems.html) and mingw (http://www.mingw.org/reporting_bugs) makes sense to me, but reporting direcly to gcc (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) should be fine as well.

Comment: @MarcGlisse as discussed in http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Sep/msg01096.html  and  http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice/2011-June/014417.html the same problem happens on OS X with gcc 4.2 ; these posts  are from 2009 and 2011 respectively  and the problem happens to both getline and cin. May be the bug is reported already.

Comment: same bug but on OS X http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962685/xcode-stl-c-debug-compile-error

Comment: Looking at mingw: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1666/ they say to report to gcc directly. Looking at gcc, the closest I find are: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54173 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53838 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33021 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64504 but they all involve at least one other option (-fwhole-program, -fvisibility). In any case, std::string was completely rewritten for gcc-5.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I believe the problem is caused by different ABI under `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. I was struck by this in past.

Answer (score 1):

`_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` changes ABI of STL classes (i.e. layout of structs, including streams and `std::string`):

```
To use the libstdc++ debug mode, compile your application with the compiler 
flag -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG. Note that this flag changes the sizes and behavior of 
standard class templates such as std::vector, and therefore you can only link 
code compiled with debug mode and code compiled without debug mode if no 
instantiation of a container is passed between the two translation units.
```

(from [official docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode)).

Your app (compiled with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`) passes `std::string` to `std::cin::operator >>` in `libstdc++.dll` (compiled without this macro) and thus violates the requirement above. Such violations normally manifest in runtime crashes: see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-10/msg00077.html) or [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53324) for concrete examples.

Comment: Libstdc++ does not document that you have to recompile libstdc++ for debug mode (they do for the thread sanitizer or other options), so I think it is not supposed to cause a conflict.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks, I added a link to STL docs (OP is passing `string` across incompatible modules).